# How to check if an address is payable

Tags: solidity, payable

I'm working on a contract that will pay token owners.

I'd like to check if an address is payable before sending.

I know I can cast to payable like so:

```
payable(address);
```

How can I check if the address is payable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `payable` cast is just syntactic sugar, and it will only throw when attempting to send.

You can verify whether an address is payable by attempting to send 0 wei.

```
function isPayable(address testAddress) private returns (bool) {
  return payable(testAddress).send(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why check if a address is payable?
The updated Solidity documentation say this:

> ...
> This change was done since the compiler cannot determine whether or
> not these addresses are payable or not, so it now requires an explicit
> conversion to make this requirement visible.

That means Solidity compiler doesn't  recognize if an address is payable or not. To solve your problem, in my opinion you mustn't check the address but call directly the `transfer()` function for send eth to token owners. The function will return an error if the address isn't payable.

See other information at this [link](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html?highlight=payable#new-restrictions).

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out I will update with an answer